# Interpretation of permutest in relation to plot in R

Tags: r, variance, data-visualization

I used permtest.betadispers function from the vegan package to test whether or not the within-group variance is statistically different amongst 4 groups.

The p-value of permutest < 0.05 ---> the difference in variance is significant.

I used the plot function to create the following:

[image]

Given that there is a large extent of overlap in the plot, is it still coherent with the permutest?

Comment: Doesn't any test of variances compare the sizes, shapes, and orientations of the ellipses?  How would their overlap be directly relevant?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. The fact that their PCo are quite within the same region, does not have direct implications on the dispersion of data within groups. However, I asked because the majority of the examples which I encountered, a significant difference in variances was accompanied by a plot where the ellipses did not overlap, and I wanted to ensure that I was interpreting my results correctly.

Comment: In those plots the ellipses must have been erected around the group means.  In the plot you show here, the group means have been removed, making the ellipses concentric--which forces a visual overlap.